# What does "typed=False" mean?

Tags: python

I'm looking at the (presumably) built-in module called "typing.py", and I'm trying to understand what's going on in there. I'm specifically looking at the code below, where we see an input argument called "typed=False". What does that even mean?

As I understand it, "func=None" appears to mean "no function is allowed in the inputs" (correct me if I'm wrong), where "func" refers to the object-type "function" (which presumably most programmers are familiar with because it's a basic concept). But what about "typed=False"?

```
def _tp_cache(func=None, /, *, typed=False):
    """Internal wrapper caching __getitem__ of generic types with a fallback to
    original function for non-hashable arguments.
    """
    def decorator(func):
        cached = functools.lru_cache(typed=typed)(func)
        _cleanups.append(cached.cache_clear)

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwds):
            try:
                return cached(*args, **kwds)
            except TypeError:
                pass  # All real errors (not unhashable args) are raised below.
            return func(*args, **kwds)
        return inner

    if func is not None:
        return decorator(func)

    return decorator
```

Comment: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/extension/python/notes/node66.html

Comment: in python, the `argument=value` syntax in a function definition is just defining a default value, if the function is called without that argument (i.e. those arguments are optional). So in this function, if `func` is not passed into the function, it will be set to `None`, and likewise if `typed` is not passed in, it will be set to `False`. See here for more: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Comment: Can you clarify what you do and do not understand about this? Do you know what keyword arguments and default values are? Are you wondering *specifically* about what the argument does for `_tp_cache`, an internal method of a module intended primarily for static inspection and not usually used by beginners? Are you aware of and have you read up on the ``typed`` parameter of ``functools.lru_cache``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I understand it, "func=None" appears to mean "no function is allowed in the inputs" (correct me if I'm wrong), where "func" refers to the object-type "function" (which presumably most programmers are familiar with because it's a basic concept). But what about "typed=False"?

None of that is correct.

`func` is a parameter name, not a type.  `=None` means that it defaults to `None` if no value is provided.  `typed` is another parameter name; `=False` means it defaults to `False`.  The `*` and `/` in the parameters list indicate that `func` is a positional parameter (i.e. it's always just the first argument, the caller doesn't need to say `func=`) and `typed` is a keyword argument (i.e. it must always be specified as `typed=SOMETHING` by the caller).

Trying to understand Python code without having a basic understanding of Python syntax is going to be extremely difficult; it's not something that you can guess at as you've attempted to do here, especially if you're diving straight into decorator (higher-order) functions, which are a relatively advanced feature and require that you already have a *very* firm grasp of how basic functions work.

I recommend making your way through a Python tutorial, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/.

Comment: hi Samwise! I have already studied multiple Python tutorials, but that doesn't mean that I have fully understood everything. In order for me to fully understand everything, I need to challenge myself like I'm doing now. Your answer helps me fill knowledge gaps in my mind and increase my ability to identify the concepts that the tutorials describe in theory (or with limited examples). I actually recognize the things you say, but didn't realize that this principle applied in this context. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It might help to go through a tutorial that involves writing some of your own code -- the things you're getting hung up on are absolutely fundamental pieces of a function definition, so maybe some practice is what's needed to help internalize the concepts.  Good luck!